# Allow a (status) message on pages chronic/timeline via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-activity, facebook-fql, message

on https://www.facebook.com/SITENAME/allactivity I can see all postings, other users have published on the page's chronic.
If the option for moderating postings on my page is enabled, I can manually publish/remove every posting made on my page (https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=356113237741414 --> the first paragraph).

I hope you understand which function I mean ... :-)

Now my question: Is it possible to publish/remove a posting, which is actually hidden on my pages wall, with the (Graph)API?

Comment: After some research I found out, that posting "is_hidden" = "true" to https://graph.facebook.com/111111_222222 the posting disappears. But this does not solve my problem. I want to set the status of the hidden postings (which have to be set to hidden/published) like in the "activity protocol"... Can some help me?